# Two questions about oaths

Tags: parents, children, oaths, kaffarah

I have two questions.
If a parent is paying kaffarah for their child who broke oaths does the child have to tell the parent what the oaths were? Also if you forgot how many oaths you've done would you get punished?

Comment: First of all it should be clarified whether children have to pay kafarah at all in such case. Secondly if so, whether parents are allowed to pay it on their behalf which I would doubt.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I know you sent that message last year. But are parents allowed to pay kaffarah for their children or not?

Answer (score 0):

According to some scholars, the child doesn't allow to oath without father's permission. So such oaths is not valid.[ref](https://iqna.ir/fa/news/3936520/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D9%82%D8%B3%D9%85-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86-%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%87-%D9%BE%D8%AF%D8%B1-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA)